# In racket I have created a function to find the maximum value in a list but some of my test cases aren't working, why aren't some of them working?

Tags: list, struct, scheme, racket

I have created a function that finds the maximum value in a list, the function  should be working but i may have made an error somewhere in my code.

Here is my code,

```
(define-struct ls (first rest))
;; a Ls is either
;; '(), or
;; (make-ls first rest) where first is an Int and rest is a Ls.

(define (ls-max L)
  (cond
    [(empty? L) 0]
    [(empty? (ls-rest L)) (ls-first L)]
    [(< (ls-first L) (ls-first (ls-rest L))) (ls-max (ls-rest L))]))
```

Here are three test cases I have made that are correct and show my code is working.

```
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 2 (make-ls 4 '()))) 4)
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 3 (make-ls 10 '()))) 10)
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 12 (make-ls 23 (make-ls 33 '())))) 33)
```

As you can see I said the largest value in the first test was 4 which was correct, the largest value for the second test was 10 which was correct and the largest value in the third test was 33 which was correct.

However, for these 4 other cases my tests are all incorrect and I have no clue why. If the code is correct why are only the first three tests correct but these last 4 aren't and if my code is incorrect why does the first three tests work. I'm very confused why this is happening with my code

```
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 22 (make-ls -32 (make-ls 12 (make-ls -3 '()))))) 22)
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls -2 (make-ls -23 (make-ls 0 (make-ls -1 '()))))) 0)
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 10 (make-ls 9 (make-ls 222 (make-ls 223 '()))))) 223)
(check-expect (ls-max (make-ls 2 (make-ls 3 (make-ls 4 (make-ls 7 (make-ls -1 (make-ls 72
            (make-ls 22 (make-ls 90 '()))))))))) 90)
```

Essentially, I want to know why my first three tests are correct but these last 4 tests are incorrect.

I just realized there definitely has to be an error in my code. the first three tests only worked because the largest value was the last value in the list, I'm unsure now the error in my code now.

Comment: What your function return in case `(>= (ls-first L) (ls-first (ls-rest L)))`?

Comment: It should be seeing if the first l's is smaller than the second l's in the list. I'm still trying to better understand data structures so It's possible i'm very wrong here. I basically tried to alter
     (<  (first L) (first (rest L))) and changed it. If I change my code to modify "<" into ">=" all the tests fail.

Comment: `(define (ls-max L) (define (max a b) (if (> b a) b a)) (define (helper current-max L) (if (empty? L) current-max (helper (max current-max (ls-first L)) (ls-rest L)))) (helper (ls-first L) (ls-rest L)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the maximum value in a list, it's not enough to compare one element with the next one: the maximum value could be way ahead in the list, hence you need to recursively compare the current element with the maximum *in the rest of the list*, like this:

```
(define (ls-max L)
  (cond
    ; I'd rather return #f for the empty list base case
    [(empty? L) #f]
    ; Base case: single-element list
    [(empty? (ls-rest L)) (ls-first L)]
    ; If current element is the max, return it
    [(>= (ls-first L) (ls-max (ls-rest L))) (ls-first L)]
    ; Otherwise the max is in the rest of the list. As an
    ; optimization we could use a `let` to avoid making the
    ; recursive call twice, left as an exercise for the reader
    [else (ls-max (ls-rest L))]))
```